# How to convert a text in xml to a hyperlink in html using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How to convert a text in xml to a hyperlink in html using xslt.

my Xml code is

```html
<Steps>          
  <Filepath>C:\Test\Capture\050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png</Filepath>
</Steps>
```

to convert it into html my xslt code looks like

```html
<td width='15%'>
  <xsl:element name="a">
 <xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="./Filepath"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select="./Filepath"/>
  </xsl:element>              
</td>
```

Now this code writes the entire path of the file in html, but I want to write only "File" in the html with the hyperlink to the location of the file.

My current generated html code is given below

```css
C:\Test\Capture\050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png
```

```html
<td width="15%"><a href="C:\Test\Capture\050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png">C:\Test\Capture\050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png</a></td>
```

What I want is

```html
<td width="15%"><a href="C:\Test\Capture\050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png">File</a></td>
```

Can anyone help me what change I need to do in xslt.

Comment: In the last example you want "File" as the content of the `<a>`? Or is that a typo for "050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it to have the value:

```
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="./Filepath"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="./Filepath"/> <!--This is the link text -->
  </xsl:element>
```

So change it to:

```
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="./Filepath"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    File
  </xsl:element>
```

Comment: This will also add in white space around the word 'File'. HTML tends to collapse it anyway and if it's in a `<td>` on it's own it won't make a difference, but in some cases this will end up with spacing you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Or shortly:

```
<a href="{Filepath}">File</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<Steps>          
  <Filepath>C:\Test\Capture\050615165617TC001_05_06_1516_57_11.png</Filepath>
</Steps>
```

Comment: Please do not post nonsense.